# Selenium - press button on numerical keyboard (numerical scope)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have numerical touch pad (1-9) in my program, the thing which needs to be tested there is to check whether when user is typing numbers which ends on endings: **1 to 9** like for example 0,01/ 0,33 / 4,46 then system throws notification: "Invalid price"

Numbers can only end on: 5 or 0, then there is a possibility to make payment.

As a Selenium beginner I don't have any ideas what should be done there. I've started from taking string values from those fields:

```
        var number1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'1')]")).Text;
        var number2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'2')]")).Text;
        var number3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'3')]")).Text;
        var number4 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'4')]")).Text;
        var number6 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'6')]")).Text;
        var number7 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'7')]")).Text;
        var number8 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'8')]")).Text;
        var number9 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'9')]")).Text;
```

Any hints?

Comment: As a user, how would I know that I entered an invalid price? What does the notification look like? Is it red text on the page or a popup or ?

Comment: @JeffC When user is entering price with mentioned ending (like. 0,01, 3,14 or 3,12) and press "Pay" button, there is pop-up notification with label: "Invalid price" at the top corner of the screen and nothing is added to the basket.

Comment: So how are you wanting to verify this? Are you entering random numbers and then want to check what is in the field before Pay is clicked or are you entering specific valid and invalid prices, clicking Pay, and then want to check if the popup occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Try making illegal sequence by clicking the relevant elements:

```
    WebElement number2 =
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
           "//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'2')]"));
    WebElement quote = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
          "//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,',')]"));
    WebElement submit = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
          "//div[@class='numpad-button primary-button' and contains(.,'submit')]"));

        // Test invalid price
        number2.click();
        number2.click();
        quote.click();
        number2.click();
        number2.click();
        submit.click();

        // Test expected exception here
```

The code is in Java so it requires C# adjustments from you.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. I need to somehow make if statement or something similar. In your example how I can do the assertion?

Comment: You need to catch an exception or error message from the UI after inputting the invalid price. But first you must develop the invalid price scenario successfully. Did you manage to do that?

Comment: Not really.....I'm able to type specific number, let's say 3,14. Then this number is in the field, later I can use ."Text" functionality to take the value, after that maybe I will trim the number somehow to gain last number and finally create "if" statement to check whether number ends with correct or incorrect ending. Does it make sense to you :)?

Comment: Please update your original code with current scenario and add exception message